# keyboard scrolls up and down when the page loads in ipad app (ios6)

Tags: html, ios6, iphone-web-app

I have converted a website to a **ipad app (ios 6)** using the option **"Add to Homescreen"** in safari browser, i have input fields in the page when the app loads the page then the virtual keyboard is shown and hides automatically, in **safari browser** working is fine, issue is only in the app

and it also preventing the user input in the input field,when any key is input-ed then the keyboard scrolls down,

Answers regarding the question is appreciable and thanks in advance

Comment: Have you googled about this?

Comment: yes i did but i cant figure out this problem!!